# What happened to the google keyword service?

Tags: google-ads-api

I know that google used to provide a service some time back where you could enter a keyword and google would tell you how many searches have been made using the exact and related keywords. This was a very useful feature while performing SEO(Search Engine Optimization). However I cannot find that particular tool anywhere. Has the service been discontinued? If yes, then what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

It has been replaced by the 'Keyword Planner:

https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool

Some of the options are different, but you cans till get keyword and number of searched from it.